# How to set super-user privileges in CiviCRM for MySQL? CiviCRM requesting for multilanguage support

Tags: joomla, mysql

I have properly installed CiviCRM 10.0, PHP version 7.2, in Joomla 3.6.5 on Linux shared hosting. Works perfectly!

Now that we have configure the Spanish language in Joomla and in CiviCRM set to "Yes" the inherit CMS language option, at the bottom of the page comes this note:

"In order to use this functionality, the installation's database user must have privileges to create triggers and views (in MySQL 5.0 – and in MySQL 5.1 if binary logging is enabled – this means the SUPER privilege). This install either does not seem to have the required privilege enabled. (Multilingual support currently cannot be enabled on installations with enabled logging.)"

Anyone knows where to check and how to set super-user privileges in CiviCRM for this particular issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask your hosting provider to give the database user the permission to create triggers and views. You only need super privileges if you're on an old version of mysql. Since you say you're on shared hosting they may not want to give those privileges, but try asking.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Asked the hosting provider and won't do it for security reasons. Therefore we are opting for different subdomain sites for different languages.